# Can we read structured stream data which is available in cosmos using U-sql

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Can we read structured stream data which is available in cosmos 
using Usql

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it needs to be asked in the context of the Microsoft internal Stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Structured stream files are not exposed as a user-object in U-SQL in Azure Datalake Analytics. If you create U-SQL tables, they are currently stored in structured stream files though.

If you are wondering how to access existing structured stream files in U-SQL in Cosmos clusters, please use the Microsoft internal stack overflow to ask your question.

Thanks!